# How can a Node.js library register for HTTP requests on a particular URL path?

Tags: javascript, web-services, node.js

I am writing a library for a web service in Node.js. My library needs to handle all HTTP requests with a particular URL prefix (Eg, /_docs/*).

I want people to be able to use my library without changing much of their code.

The API should look something like this:

```
server = http.createServer(function(req, res) { ... });    
...
myLibrary.listen(server, '_docs/');
```

or

```
server = new http.Server();
myLibrary.listen(server, '_docs/');
server.on('request', function(req, res) { ... });
```

If I merely register another event handler on the server object, the user's http request handler will be called on all HTTP requests as well. My code will race with the user's 404 handler.

Socket.io has a similar problem, and [they solve it](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node/blob/master/lib/socket.io/listener.js#L29-37) by making their .listen() function move all existing http request handlers into a private array. When HTTP requests come in, if their code doesn't handle the URL it calls the listeners in the array. However, as far as I can tell this wouldn't work in the second example I've shown above.

Whats the best way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/)? Router middleware provides rich [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) / [Express](http://expressjs.com/)-like routing.

**Example**

```
connect.router(function(app){
  app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res, next){
    // populates req.params.id
  });
  app.put('/user/:id', function(req, res, next){
    // populates req.params.id
  });
})
```

For advanced use look at http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing.

Comment: Wouldn't this require that everyone who uses my library uses Connect? Can Connect coexist with vanilla request handlers?